# How to blow up an alien skyscraper?

Tags: science-based, engineering, megastructures, explosions

In the story a group of people needs to bring down a huge alien skyscraper (I have intended it to be around two (2) miles high but I can modify this based on the answers). Note that the alien skyscraper is on Earth and that the people in question have military training (knowledge how to construct a bomb, how to operate bombs) but don't have nor access, nor time to acquire firepower in the range of nuclear weapons and such.

I also had in mind that they would combine many types of bombs to bring down the skyscraper like shockwave demolition bombs as well as thermite: as to ensure that the alien software in the said building (which contains important data collection for aliens) is completely destroyed. It doesn't have to be controlled demolition so the whole thing comes down pretty, it is actually better that it comes down in a chaotic manner, but fall down it must.

How would a stealth bomb squad place those bombs and thermite to ensure buildings destruction and how much explosives would be needed (given that an alien buildings are enhanced and hard to bring down) to achieve this goal?

Comment: How strong this alien tower is? Is it similar to our skyscraper? What is the technology the alien have? Alien was supposed to have superior technology, such as detecting any stealthed units, very wide radar, automatic defense turret, and such.

Comment: Please explain the size and structure of this foreign skyscraper. I can easily think of two miles high structures which _cannot_ be demolished with current technology. For example, [Mount Whitney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Whitney) in California.

Comment: "place those bombs and termite to ensure buildings destruction and how much explosives would be needed (given that an alien buildings are enhanced and hard to bring down)" -- there you have it. It can go *any way*, depending on this unknown alien hardening. It might be so hardened that not even a fusion warhead can take it out, most of its energy being blown outwards and no access being available to put it where it could do enough damage. Or it might have subtle vulnerabilities and be sensitive to nano-unravelers, or enbrittled by beta rays - just poison the paint used to whitewash and wait.

Comment: I like the idea of a 'termite' bomb...though it might be effective only against wooden or wood-based structures.

Answer (score 4):

1. A plane hitting partway up the building worked on 911.
2. Fires can still bring down big buildings.

I feel like those things are kind of tired.  I propose **miners**.

From http://www.syler.com/SiegeWarfare/fnlassault/mining.html

> There was an alternative to pounding down a wall with artillery fire:
>   dig under and destroy from below. "Mines were preferred to breaching
>   by guns, not only as being more effective against works of a
>   provisional character, which were largely composed of earth, but as
>   likely to be more successful in the formation of breaches even in
>   works with masonry revetments; for the old masonry walls were
>   exceedingly thick, and strongly consolidated, and the breaching of
>   them, by artillery fire, difficult and expensive," so said 19th
>   century military historian and Royal Engineer Lt. Colonel W. G. Ross
>   who studied fortifications and sieges of the English Civil War.*

It is an old method of warfare - old enough that the defenders might not be expecting it.  I say old but nothing would please me more than to have some savant link up some instances of this strategy as used in modern conflicts.  It can be updated with new tech: specifically "Driller Mike" or some comparable tunnel boring machine.

Here is Driller Mike and its namesake Killer Mike.
[image]

A machine like this might not be considered a military threat and might not be guarded.  Also machines like this are not in constant use and one might be in long term storage, ready to be appropriated.

That is the plan: steal boring machine, dig deep under tower.  I can envision the scene where they have the tunnel dug and are leaving the explosives. Maybe they try to save Driller Mike too.